# Converting child to screen space in cocos2d for android

Tags: java, android, cocos2d-iphone

I am an android developer...

currently I have 2 images, ImageA and ImageB. ImageB is a child of ImageA

Assuming ImageA position is in (100, 100); then ImageB local position is (10, 0);

So what I'm trying to do is how can I retrieve the screen position of ImageB whereby it will return me (110, 100) instead of (10, 0)?

thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Objective-C you would do this:

```
[image convertToWorldSpace:image.position];
```

I assume cocos2d-android has the same method, the syntax will be different of course.

Comment: thanks, but i can not read Ob-c code like you cant read korean.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get by adding the positions of parent and child to get proper position for child on screen

```
ImageA.getPosition().x+ImageB.getPosition().x
```